# How to lint indent based SASS?

Tags: sass, eslint

I am trying to add linting for SugarSS to my project. I've added lint-staged command to my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint-staged": "$(yarn bin)/lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    ...
    "app/assets/styles/**/*.sass": [
      "prettier --write",
      "stylelint --fix --syntax sugarss",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
```

When I run `npm run lint-staged` it outputs

```
✖ prettier --write found some errors. Please fix them and try committing again.


[error] path/to/style.sass: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ";" (3:16)
[error]   1 | h1.question
[error]   2 |   overflow: visible
[error] > 3 |   padding-right: 12px
[error]     |                ^
[error]   4 |   color: #333
[error]   5 |
[error]   6 | #questions h4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my_project@1.0.0 lint-staged: `$(yarn bin)/lint-staged`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my_project@1.0.0 lint-staged script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Seems like that eslint tries to lint my `path/to/style.sass` with the new [SASS 3](https://sass-lang.com/) syntax

How can I set up linting for SugarSS syntax in package.json? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set up linting for SugarSS with the following setup:

```
# .stylelintrc
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-sugarss-recommended"
}
```

And in package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "stylelint-config-sugarss-recommended": "^1.1.0"
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint-staged": "$(yarn bin)/lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "app/assets/styles/**/*.sass": [
      "stylelint --fix --syntax sugarss",
      "git add"
    ],
    ...
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint-staged"
  ]
}
```